# XPath Selenium: Select a node based on existance of a peer node

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Folks,

I am trying to understand how to work with combination of peer nodes

Part 1 of my question

I need help with putting together xpath expression, in order to fill a collection only with links, which have span as a peer node (exists).

a) Add to collection

```
<div style="font-weight:bold;padding-top:4px;padding-left:10px;text-align:left;white-space:nowrap;">
    <a class="LeftNavLink" href="find/all-years/alfa-romeo" style="margin-left:14px;">Alfa Romeo</a><span style="font-weight:normal;"> (121)</span>
</div>
```

b) Do not add to collection

```
<div style="font-weight: bold; padding-top: 4px; padding-left: 10px;">
    <a href="find?tags=convertible" class="LeftNavLink">Convertibles</a>
</div>
```

Part 2 of my question

What would be xpath expression, in order to fill a collection only with links, which have span as a peer node with specific attribute (ex. style="font-weight" not style="font-weight:normal;")

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, this is fairly simplistic, but given your HTML, should work:

```
//div/span/../a
```

This will find `<div>`, which has `<span>` as a child, return to parent (which is `<div>`), then find `<a>`.

For your second question:

```
//div/span[contains(@style, 'font-weight:') and not(contains(@style,'font-weight:normal;'))]/../a
```

The difference here is that for `<span>`, use `contains()` to find `style="font-weight:"`, then `and` it with `not(contains())` to exclude `style="font-weight:normal;"`

For your last question, you're not going to get text from `<a>` and its peer `<span?`. I would suggest using har07's approach:

```
//div[a and span]/span
```

Use that to get another `List`:

```
List<WebElement> span1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath ("//div[a and span]/span"));
```

Comment: Richard, one more thing. I got a collection of links I need: List<WebElement> links3 = driver.findElements(By.xpath ("//div/span/../a")); Now I am going through it in order to get text of both links and corresponding spans: for (WebElement link:links3){linkText = link.getText();} How do I get text of the span? In the my example, it is "(121)"

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can select `<div>` having `<span>` and `<a>` children, then get the `<a>` child this way :

```
//div[a and span]/a
```

You may want to add some filters (`[....]`) to be more specific as necessary. The 2nd requirement can use similar XPath, but with more specific filter for the `<span>` element, for example :

```
//div[a and span[
                  contains(@style, 'font-weight') 
                    and 
                  not(contains(@style, 'font-weight:normal'))
                 ]]/a
```